# Java Dropdown Checklist

Tags: java, list, jlist, jcombobox

I understand how to make a multiple-select list box using [`JLists`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) but I want to add [`JCheckBox`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JCheckBox.html)es to the list and make it dropdown like. The best visual representation I have found online is [dropdown-check-list](http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/).

What would be the best way to accomplish the above? 
I was thinking of a [TableList](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorialJWS/uiswing/events/ex6/TableListSelectionDemo.jnlp). Any suggestions?

Comment: Why is a multiple-select list box not what you want? To me, it would be the expected user interface control.

Comment: So you actually want JComboBox with checkboxes?

Comment: @Dmitry - Yes but with multiple-select. JComboBox does not support multiple-select. 

@Thomas Owens - A multiple-select list box is nice but does not have the dropdown effect. I am trying to save space. My userbase may not know how to use a multiple-select list so I thought checkboxes would be nice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This code snippet](http://www.coderanch.com/t/343024/Swing-AWT-SWT-JFace/java/Components-inside-JComboBox) may help you.

The basic idea is to handle actionPerformed or mouseClick events by yourself and keep states of the corresponding items (checked/unchecked) in your own data structure. You'll be able to use that data structure for rendering checkboxes in a dropdown

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `JList`, then its as simple as changing the `ListCellRenderer` to return a `JCheckbox` component.

EDIT:
For JCombobox, you can use `combobox.setRenderer(myListRenderer);`

Comment: This should work for displaying a Checkbox in a list. How would I make the List look like a ComboBox?

Comment: A JComboBox uses a ListCellRenderer to draw its items, just like a JList does: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setRenderer%28javax.swing.ListCellRenderer%29

Comment: @twodayslate...see the EDIt in my answer :)